# Removing ghost keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

On my computer I see an Irish keyboard layout in the language bar. 
I don't know any Irish and English (USA) is my default langage with QWERTY being its only keyboard layout.
How do I permanently delete the Irish GA keyboard layout? I've accomplished several things to help such as removing the keyboard shortcut keys to switch languages but I can't seem to identify the source of this additional keyboard layout.

Any suggestions as to next steps?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Languages]
[image]

Comment: i have the same problem, and also US English + Hebrew keyboard. Maybe it's related?
I deleted the 3rd language (UK English!) but it's still there, even after few restarts.

Answer (score 2):

[try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx488.png)

In language settings, scroll down and click 'administrative language settings'.
On the "administrative" tab, click 'copy settings'.
Check the two options and click ok.

Finally, sign out and sign in.